# Testing 4kv supply

Tags: high-voltage, testing

I need to test if the trigger coil on my strobe circuit is working or not. But it has a 4kV output. How do I test such high voltages?

Comment: For clarification about possible power dissipation it would be nice if you could describe the output pulse a bit more  (at least duration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a voltage divider like this.  It will cut the voltage by a factor of 1000, so 4kV will appear as 4V which you can easily measure with any meter.

[image]

Be very careful with the connection to the 10M resistor, since it will have 4KV on it.  The rest of the circuit is safe.

If the 4kV was on continuously, the resistor would be dissipating 1.6W but the OP says it is part of a strobed circuit, so that value can be substantially lowered (unless there is some sort of failure ode where the 4kV can remain on -- than you should use a 2.5W resistor).

But assuming the 4kV is not on more than 1% of the time, you can get by with an regular 1/8W resistor.  Be sure both resistors are 1%.

Comment: Be careful with your choice of 10M resistor. 1st be aware that its going to dissipate 1.6W, and then make sure its rated to have 4kV across it without arcing. A series of 10 1M resistors would be easier.

Comment: A regular 250mW resistor is rated for 100 or 200V, so still not a good fit! cc: @brhans

Comment: The 2,5W watt resistor I found is rated at 10kV.  Look at its [datasheet](http://www.ohmite.com/cat/res_maximox.pdf).

Comment: You've missed a point. Resistor wattage is essentially irrelevant. The reason? This is a strobe trigger. Yes, you get 4 kV and a pretty amazing power dissipation, but only for a microsecond or less. Voltage rating is what counts in this case. And the HV connection is not the only thing to worry about. Ground is nearly as dangerous, since if you become part of the return path you will get a very nice jolt. Not as bad as the HV connection, since the 10M protects you, but still not fun.

Comment: I agree with @WhatRoughBeast on this one - The strobe trigger is most likely not 4kV for very long, so the DC power rating of the resistors is not really an issue. The resistor divider is still a good idea to get a reasonable and measureable voltage signal though, perhaps through a buffer op-amp IC. Make sure all resistors used are good quality, and aim for 1% precision just to ensure it's safe and accurate voltage

Comment: @KyranF I missed the part of the question where the 4kV is part of a strobe circuit.  Assuming there is no failure mode where the 4kV can be on continuously, then the resistor wattage can be substantially reduced.  I'll edit my answer (again).

Comment: that's okay man! you are right, there may be a failure mode where the 4kV stays energized - there may be other issues worse than the voltage divider eventually burning out though.. but it's hard to say without seeing the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Also, if you use a buffer amp, it needs to be fast. Strobe trigger pulses are very narrow - microsecond time scale.